# Save my app data through phone restore - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

What technology is available for me to save app data (Core Data) so that when a user switched phones and has a fresh phone they still have my app information?

I have heard people say cloudKit, however that seems overkill, I don't want the functionality to handoff between devices. I simply want the app data to be backed up when the user has iCloud backup enabled for the app.

If the answer is iCloud, what steps must I follow to enable such behavior?  I have seen links to cloudKit tutorials, however all of them cover an extensive amount of material and work, and what I want to achieve seems simple enough.  (As stated before I do not want handoff between devices, I have no need for it.).

Thank you for the suggestions

Edit: I have gone into "capabilities" and switched on iCloud.  Now in my iPhone settings under iCloud backup my app appears.  However does simply switching on iCloud capabilities persist your app data to iCloud Drive or backup?

Ex: Go to Settings -> Account -> iCloud -> Scroll down to iCloud Drive and ensure it is checked.  My app shows there, but I haven't included any code to implement this (I simply flipped the switch in capabilities)

So from my current understanding I create Core Data as normal, however I add a listener for an changes/updates/deletes/creation of the persistentStore and upload/update iCloud via document storage when this happens? I was under the impression that iCloud was being depreciated and that only cloudKit will remain?

Edit 3:

iCloud = Depreciated, therefore the one and only solution available is cloudKit.

How does one implement cloudKit to interact correctly with Core Data?

**What comes to mind is the following:**
- Enable cloudKit

- Listen to all changes to persistent Store and reflect these changes in CloudKit (somehow)
- On app start check to see if CloudKit matches core data (somehow)
- if they are not the same then download cloudKit data and save to core data (somehow)

Please clarify if this is not the correct route to proceed down

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149 discusses iCloud Document storage.  You can choose to store your Sqlite database (Core data is Sqlite underneath) in iCloud.

Comment: I see, so Core data being an Sqlite db would utilize iCloud Document storage?

Comment: if you already have your own server you could do it through those means as well

Comment: @TPN1994 Indeed, I am aware of that being a solution, however I am attempting to avoid a server completely due to the cost associated.  Why pay a monthly fee when there is a solution from apple somewhere free? Edit: Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Jerland2 There is no free on device solution from Apple. When your app is deleted, all associated data with it is purged. Using iCloud is the free solution that Apple provides.

Comment: @CodeBender Sorry that is exactly what I am saying.  I am aware it is iCloud, however my question is meant to convey how one goes about utilizing cloudKit to store core data such that associated data is stored in iCloud between uninstalls/phone resets. I am aware that iCloud is depreciated and cloudKit is the only solution left, however there are no tutorials I can find that highlight core data + cloudKit implementation.  Therefore I was wondering what the best approach is to implement core data + cloudKit to perform what is stated in OP.

Comment: @Jerland2 because sometimes depending on the app, forcing the user to use iCloud and placing the responsibility of storing the user's data on the user isn't such a compelling user experience (once again, depends on the very nature of the application).

Comment: @TPN1994 in this specific application, the user wouldn't interface with iCloud at all. If they have an iCloud account their data will be backed up without them ever knowing.  If they don't, then they loose out on the feature without ever knowing it existed.

Comment: @Jerland2 Hmm, could that be a potentially be an unpleasant experience? As a user, It wouldn't sit well with me if I had progress/data on the app then for whatever reason needed it to be restored and it just didn't restore because I wasn't logged into an iCloud account. But I guess if the application clearly states that it needs an iCloud account to save the data it wouldn't be too big of a deal. However, I strongly do believe that the user experience would definitely suffer. Maybe it's because I myself personally don't have an iCloud account linked to my phone :P

Comment: @TPN1994 Hmm... I can see your point, honestly it boils down to the app not making enough revenue to justify spending money every month on a server.  The work around for the time being is that the app organizes data and never promises to save it anywhere but locally.  In addition there is no feature/button/way to "restore" data. So from a user standpoint they wouldn't know that they missed out on a feature.  I agree with you the user experience could suffer.  One workaround I plan is eventually including both Dropbox & iCloud backup when time permits, which will at least give an option.

Comment: As Matt says, if the user uses backup/restore to move to the new device then the data will be there.  If you want to use CloudKit then you can look at [Seam3](https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What technology is available for me to save app data (Core Data) so that when a user switched phones and has a fresh phone they still have my app information?

There isn't any such problem. I've upgraded devices many times and nothing has ever been lost. When I got a new iPhone last year, and when I got a new iPad this year, all my apps on the new device simply showed up with the same settings and data as before on the old device.

That's the because the user who gets a new device backs up from the old device and restores to the new device. That's what I always do and it just works. You cannot reliably work around a user who is too stupid to know to do that, so I recommend not even thinking about it.

Comment: Interesting, so I don't even need to use CloudKit to enable my app to be backed up to Icloud?